# Equivalent of 'class_indices' attribute of 'flow_from_directory' object in case of 'ImageDataGenerator' object

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am following a tutorial at  https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720

I am using 'ImageDataGenerator' object and want to predict the out put using the following method.

```
pred=model.predict_generator(test_generator,
steps=10,
verbose=1)

predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(pred,axis=1)

labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
```

But I am using Keras 'ImageDataGenerator'  and 'flow_from_dataframe' object.
 'ImageDataGenerator' has no 'class_indices' attribute. How can I get the indices of the classes

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. A 'flow_from_dataframe' object has no 'class_indices' attribute, despite the manual. How did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

End to End example which uses `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe` and which answers your question of `How can I get the indices of the classes`

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
#Import from keras_preprocessing not from keras.preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers, optimizers
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def append_ext(fn):
    return fn+".png"
traindf=pd.read_csv("trainLabels.csv",dtype=str)
testdf=pd.read_csv("sampleSubmission.csv",dtype=str)
traindf["id"]=traindf["id"].apply(append_ext)
testdf["id"]=testdf["id"].apply(append_ext)
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="train/",
x_col="id",
y_col="label",
subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(32,32))

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="train/",
x_col="id",
y_col="label",
subset="validation",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(32,32))

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
test_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=testdf,
directory="test/",
x_col="id",
y_col=None,
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=False,
class_mode=None,
target_size=(32,32))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_TEST=test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=10
)

model.evaluate_generator(generator=valid_generator,
steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST)

test_generator.reset()
pred=model.predict_generator(test_generator,
steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST,
verbose=1)

predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(pred,axis=1)


labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
```

Finally, we `print` the Classes as shown below:

```
print(predictions)
```

Output of above `print` statement is:

```
['bird',
 'dog',
 'bird',
 'cat',
 'horse',
 'deer',
 'deer',
 'airplane',
 'cat',
 'cat',
 'ship',
 'bird',
 'automobile',..........]
```

For more information, please refer this Article written by [Vijaya Bhaskar](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-flow-from-dataframe-1fd4493d237c).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: thanks but I used the same procedure except for class_mode I used "raw" and not "categorical" since it wont work with many classes. When "raw" is used for class_mode, then train_generator does not have "class_indices" method and this method does not work